# Dependency injection in a maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, maven-plugin

I am developing a maven plugin and to make it more testable I would like to use a light-weight dependency injection framework(like Guice) to manage services etc but while I can get them to integrate with applications I haven't been able to get them integrated with my plugin.  Is there any way to do this save for doing the dependency-injection in a static fashion?

Answer (score 2):

Maven already provides you with embedded IoC container called Plexus. You can include other components

```
public class MonitorMojo
    extends AbstractMojo
{

    /**
     * The website monitor component instance that will be injected 
     * by the Plexus runtime.
     * @component
     */
    private WebsiteMonitor monitor;

    public void execute()
        throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

and refer to properties

```
@Parameter( property = "sayhi.greeting", defaultValue = "Hello World!" )
private String greeting;
```

You can find more information on [maven plugin dev site](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) and [plexus documentation](http://plexus.codehaus.org/writing-components-trail/07_01_implementing_monitor_mojo.html).

Comment: Maven 3.1.+ has brought a new dependency system, it still supports plexus api/annotations, but maven is moving to guice/jsr330, check following link: http://maven.apache.org/maven-jsr330.html

Answer (score 0):

There is also another framework (a small library) which brings better CDI support for Maven plugin development than the one referenced in carlosvin's comment (Maven JSR 330).

This is the library: [Maven CDI Plugin Utils](https://github.com/shillner/maven-cdi-plugin-utils).

It provides not only DI but also some additional concepts such as a workflow-based processing model with rollback functionality and extensibility by default.

I will publish a blog post about this library soon but I think the documentation should explain all the concepts. Btw. this is DI as known from CDI with a full-featured Weld SE container and classpath-based bean discovery!